# numpy outerproduct of sequence of arrays

Tags: numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix A (nXm) . My ultimate goal is to get Z of dimension (nXmXm) Currently I am doing it using this but can it be done without using for loop using some matrix.tensordot or matrix.multiply.outer

```
 for i in range(0,A.shape[0]):
       Z[i,:,:] = np.outer(A[i,:],A[i,:])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [numpy's Einstein summation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), like this:

```py
np.einsum('ij, ik -> ijk', a, a)
```

Just for completeness, the timing comparison with the also excellent answer (+1) from unutbu:

```py
In [39]: A = np.random.random((1000,50))

In [40]: %timeit using_einsum(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop

In [41]: %timeit using_broadcasting(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ms per loop

In [42]: %timeit orig(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.8 ms per loop
```

Which teaches me that

1. unutbu's machine is faster than mine
2. broadcasting would be slightly faster than `np.einsum`

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(0,A.shape[0]):
    Z[i,:,:] = np.outer(A[i,:],A[i,:])
```

means

```
Z_ijk = A_ij * A_ik
```

which can be computed using [NumPy broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
Z = A[:, :, np.newaxis] * A[:, np.newaxis, :]
```

`A[:, :, np.newaxis]` [has shape `(n, m, 1)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and `A[:, np.newaxis, :]` has shape
`(n, 1, m)`. Multiplying the two causes both arrays to be broadcasted up to
shape `(n, m, m)`.

NumPy multiplication is always performed elementwise.  The values along the
broadcasted axis are the same everywhere, so elementwise multiplication results
in `Z_ijk = A_ij * A_ik`.

---

```
import numpy as np

def orig(A):
    Z = np.empty(A.shape+(A.shape[-1],), dtype=A.dtype)
    for i in range(0,A.shape[0]):
        Z[i,:,:] = np.outer(A[i,:],A[i,:])
    return Z

def using_broadcasting(A):
    return A[:, :, np.newaxis] * A[:, np.newaxis, :]
```

Here is a sanity check showing this produces the correct result:

```
A = np.random.random((1000,50))
assert np.allclose(using_broadcasting(A), orig(A))
```

By choosing `A.shape[0]` to be large we get an example which shows off the
advantage of broadcasting over looping in Python:

```
In [107]: %timeit using_broadcasting(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 6.12 ms per loop

In [108]: %timeit orig(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed my A.shape[0] is large in my case.